# [logic]Give sample of 3-element set M so that M is not satisfiable, but every 2-element subset of M is satisfiable.

Tags: satisfiability

This is the Exercise 7 in 《Logic for Computer Scientist》(Uwe Schoning)

```
Exercise 7: Give an example of a 3-element set M so that M is not
satisfiable, but every 2-element subset of M is satisfiable. Generalize your
example to n-element sets.
```

I am stuck in this question for a while. I intuitively thought it was easy, while it was not for me at least :(.

I think there may be something wrong in my understanding and this answer should help me a lot .

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For $3$ elements:
$$a,b,(\text{not }(a \text{ and } b))$$
For $n$ elements:
$$a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{n-1},(\text{not }(a_1 \text{ and } a_2 \text{ and }\ldots\text{ and }a_{n-1}))$$

Comment: the Aha moment occurs i think . Thanks a lot !

Comment: Another example is $(a \leftrightarrow b) \wedge (b \leftrightarrow c) \wedge (c \leftrightarrow \neg a)$, with its obvious generalization.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi, does it meet the "3 elements in M" ? What is the actual elements ?

Comment: Well, write it like this: $\{a \leftrightarrow b, b \leftrightarrow c, c \leftrightarrow \neg a\}$.  Sorry, I'm used to switch between the two forms without even thinking.

Comment: My version of that was: force the simultaneous satisfiability of the first $(n-1)$ elements (hence why not make them all atoms), then worry about the last one.

Comment: @Keith quasi's example is more star-shaped, and mine looks more circular, but both have a rotational symmetry of sorts.  So, yes, that's the easy way to get examples that easily generalize to $n$ elements.

Comment: @Keith Here's another example, already in the $4$-element version: $\{a, a \rightarrow b, b \rightarrow c, \neg c\}$.  This may be close to what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks @FabioSomenzi, my first guess about the answer is something "symmetric rotational " form, like $AB\neg{C},A\neg{B}C,\neg{A}BC$. Your answer and quasi's gave me those "simple"  forms. I will re-think about this question. I know where i was going wrong now.

Comment: @quasi,  would you please help review my answer ?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi, would you please help review my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours thinking regarding the answers of quasi & Fabio, here is my answer.

I am willing to find a "pattern" or "constraint" so that any set of formulas meeting this "pattern" will apply to the question.

My induction :

1. from the first premise " 3 element is not satisfiable", so there are the  constraints :
   $(A\wedge{B}\rightarrow\neg{C}) \wedge (A\wedge{C}\rightarrow\neg{B}) \wedge (B\wedge{C}\rightarrow\neg{A}) $   .
   After equivalence, it shows the same thing : $A\wedge{B}\rightarrow\neg{C}$.
2. from the second premise " any 2 elements subset is satisfiable", so we have the constraints:
   $A\rightarrow{B},  B\rightarrow{C},C\rightarrow{A},B\rightarrow{A},C\rightarrow{B},C\rightarrow{A} 
     i.e. (C\leftrightarrow{B})\vee(A\leftrightarrow{B})\vee(A\leftrightarrow{C})$
3. join the constraints from step1/step2, we finally get the constraint $A\wedge{B}\rightarrow\neg{C}$.

So for any formula set which met this constraint will apply to the question.

By testing the samples given by quasi&Fabio, it is valid solutions.

Comment: If $A$, $B$, and $C$ range over formulae, then the mutual exclusion requirement is indeed that $\neg A \vee \neg B \vee \neg C$ should be valid.  The second requirement, though, is that $A \wedge B$, $B \wedge C$, and $A \wedge C$ should be (individually) satisfiable.

Comment: @Keith: To check it, just make a truth table with 8 rows, one row for each possible valuation of the triples A,B,C. Of course you need need columns for A,B,C, and for your 3 formulas, as well as the 3 paired combinations and the one triple combo.

Comment: @Keith: It's a little tedious, but then you'll know for sure.

Comment: @quasi, yes, that is what i am using in my draft paper for induction.